# Using fetch to get data from an API, how to access data after promise has resolved?

Tags: javascript

Running the below code on the console, I get an array of objects.

```
fetch('https://api.github.com/users/chriscoyier/repos')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    // Here's a list of repos!
    console.log(data)
  });
```

How can I access the data later? For example if I wanted to console.log the data[0].archive_url, after the promise has resolved? But that gives an error "Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined". How do I access that array of objects?

[image: console]

Comment: console.log(data[0].archive_url) works fine for me.

https://jsfiddle.net/dyspkd12/

Comment: Assign `data` to a global variable.

Comment: @Adriani6 I would like to access the data after the promise has resolved. That only works if I put it in the fetch request immidietly.

Comment: @deceze Could you make an example, please?

Comment: Not reproducable. @Adriani6's snippet works perfectly fine.

Comment: @Suomi I see, here's another fiddle then. https://jsfiddle.net/dyspkd12/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var myGlobalVar;

fetch('https://api.github.com/users/chriscoyier/repos')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data);
    myGlobalVar = data;
  });
```

Once this request has finished (once you see the console output), the data is now available in the variable `myGlobalVar` for you to play around with on the console. You could also use your browser's debugger to set a breakpoint in the callback function and have direct access to `data` from there.

Note that this won't work in actual code, this is only useful for the interactive console: [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/476)